# Using UpdateSingleSalesforceObject for multiple records

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

I've got a Cloudpage with Ampscript that displays record information of a custom object related to a Contact. It displays a particular field as a checkbox, which corresponds with the custom object record checkbox field. I'm using LookupRows and various Data Extensions to display multiple rows if a Contact has multiple records.
This is working fine to just show the information, but how do I push the data back if someone submits and unchecks/checks certain fields on multiple rows?

UpdateSingleSalesforceObject works perfect to update a single record, but I need to dynamically trigger this depending on the amount of records someone has, and if they made a change on particular records. Is SSJS required here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use SSJS to update data in Salesforce, there are no SSJS functions that would allow it.

You will need to get all the IDs of the records that need to be updated and update them one by one using the [UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://ampscript.guide/updatesinglesalesforceobject/) AMPscript function.

You can use a [loop](https://youtu.be/p-hNUfr1tRQ) to iterate through all the records that are related to a particular contact and update each one of them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I'm able to loop through now, but I'm having trouble pulling the checkbox values from the form itself onto the UpdateSingleSalesforceObject action. Input looks like this currently: 
 `<input type="checkbox" name="%%=v(@Id)=%%" id="%%=v(@Id)=%%" value="%%=v(@Id)=%%" %%[IF @checkboxvalue == "true" THEN]%%checked%%[ENDIF]%%><label>testlabel</label>`


My submission action is basically:

`IF RequestParameter(@Id) == true` and then the set update actions, which doesn't seem to be pulling correctly..

Comment: Checkbxes take the `on` value once submitted, see here for an explanation with examples: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/10/05/working-with-salesforce-multi-select-picklists-in-ampscript/

Comment: Great I was able to figure it out, thanks for all your help!

Comment: No problem and please remember to accept the answer by ticking the checkbox if it helped